# How to get section specific headers as output in DocBook

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, docbook, docbook-xsl

I am trying to set section and chapter specific headers for my DocBook using the following syntax:

```
<!DOCTYPE book PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DocBook XML V4.1.2//EN" "http://www.oasis-open.org/docbook/xml/4.1.2/docbookx.dtd">
<book>
    <title>My Guide to Bowling</title>
    <chapter>
         <section header="section header">
            <title>Buying the right clothes</title>
            <para>I want to buy some shoes</para>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

Then in my XSL i am doing the following customization to set the right header:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" version="1.0">

<xsl:import href="/docbook-xsl-1.79.1/fo/docbook.xsl"/>

<xsl:template name="header.content">
        <xsl:param name="pageclass"/>
        <xsl:param name="position" select="''"/>
    <fo:block>
                <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$pageclass = 'body'">
                        <xsl:choose><xsl:when test="$position = 'center'">
                                        <xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::*[@header]/@header"/>
                        </xsl:when></xsl:choose>
                </xsl:when></xsl:choose>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is working for chapters but not sections.
How to make it work for sections in the current page?

Comment: It will be easier to help if you will edit your question with whole XML and whole XSL file.

Comment: @O.F. I just added a full version of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<xsl:value-of select="ancestor-or-self::*[@header][1]/@header"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works for chapters but not for sections.

Comment: @nischayn22, will you share full input so we can analyze that. also what value you pass through param `pageclass`

Comment: Those are passed through fo. See docbook.sourceforge.net/release/xsl/1.77.0/doc/fo/

Comment: Any help on this? Thank you.

Comment: @nischayn22 for this, you have to show your actual input, so we can check this.